# How to implement an async Callback using Square's Retrofit networking library

Tags: java, android, networking, asynchronous, retrofit

As an iOS developer beginning to work with Android I came across Retrofit. I understand how to implement synchronous requests but am having trouble implementing asynchronous requests with success/failure callbacks. Specifically, the Callback syntax is unclear to me and there are no concrete examples of how to do this on the Retrofit [website](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), the Square [blogpost](http://corner.squareup.com/2013/05/retrofit-one-dot-oh.html) introducing Retrofit, or elsewhere that I've seen. Can someone please post some example code on this? I filed an issue in the Retrofit repo asking that they update the README with this info.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After some more research and just plain spending more time in the Android/Java world I figured this out, using the example from their docs.

Interface:

```
@GET("/user/{id}/photo")  
void listUsers(@Path("id") int id, Callback<Photo> cb);
```

Implementation:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setServer("baseURL")     
            .build();
ClientInterface service = restAdapter.create(ClientInterface.class);

Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void success(Object o, Response response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

    }
};
service.listUsers(666, callback);
```

Comment: Don't forget to call setExecutors() when creating your restAdapter.

Comment: @SeanPONeil you only need to setExecutors() when you want the callback to happen off the main thread too.

Comment: Not at the time when I posted that. Square added sane defaults for the executors.

Comment: @Alfie Hanssen : I have a noob query for retrofit. In the success method, what's the difference between o and Response ? Which one should I use for getting say, JSON data sent from the server ?

Comment: @Raj
'o' is the request object, 'response' is the actual result.
You would get the JSON data from the 'response' object.

Comment: @StormeHawke obviously I did, no one responded. So it was a kind of desperate move. Anyways I did solve the issues eventually.

Comment: I still exactly dont get How to implement Retrofit callback

Comment: With refrofit 2.0 there is no RestAdapter anymore.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32614103/192961) for the Retrofit 2.0 way of dealing with callbacks.