# Getting an SSL exception in retrofit

Tags: android, wordpress, webservice-client, retrofit

I have some problems using retrofit as my web communication interface against a php webservice contained in a worpress website - upon a call for one of the JSON API methods in the WP site I get an SSL exception on my android client even though I run over http and not https.

Here is my code -

```
public class RestApi {
    private static final String API_URL = "https://tmc.co.nf/api";
    private SmokeTalkRest service;
    interface SmokeTalkRest {

        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/get_nonce")
        void getNonce(@Field("controller") String controller, @Field("method") String method, Callback<String> callback);
    }

    public RestApi() {

        // Create a very simple REST adapter which points the GitHub API
        // endpoint.
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setServer(API_URL).build();

        // Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
        service = restAdapter.create(SmokeTalkRest.class);
    }

    public void getNonceForMethod(Method method, Callback<String> callback) {
        service.getNonce("user", method.name(), callback);
    }
}
```

The get nonce is called upon a button click, did someone already bumped into that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you are having is your trying to call retrofit but not using the async version. The callback is probably the easiest to use.

```
@GET("/user/{id}")  
void listUser(@Path("id") int id, Callback<User> cb);

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setServer("baseURL")     
            .build();
ClientInterface service = restAdapter.create(ClientInterface.class);

Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void success(Object o, Response response) {
//do something
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

    }
};
service.listUser(1, callback);
```

[How to implement an async Callback using Square's Retrofit networking library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034465/how-to-implement-an-async-callback-using-squares-retrofit-networking-library)

Android now requires you to do any webrequests async otherwise it will error out.

Also, retorfit will convert/parse the object for you so you dont have to. It saves time when it comes to creating async tasks and setting up the parsing. It also give a nice standard to go by when doing requests as well.

Comment: Well the thing is as for now I'm doing exactly the same using a callback to set some text view with the returning answer, and I still get the running on UI thread exception

Comment: I would suggest providing some more code and some more info on what your currently doing. Also attach the logcat so we can filter out what the issue might be.

Comment: Hi kalel, 
I managed to solve that problem eventually however I now get an SSL exception even though the server runs on http and not on https - any ideas?
I edited my question and added some code.

Comment: "https:" - remove the s in https