# Service methods cannot return void. retrofit

Tags: retrofit

This is my method in Interface. I am calling this function but app crash with this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot
>   return void.
>       for method RestInterface.getOtp

```
//post method to get otp for login
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/store_login")
void getOtp(@Header("YOUR_APIKEY") String apikey, @Header("YOUR_VERSION") String appversion,
            @Header("YOUR_VERSION") String confiver, @Field("mobile") String number, Callback<Model> cb);
```

And this is the code where I am calling this function

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .build();

    RestInterface restApi = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);
    restApi.getOtp("andapikey", "1.0", "1.0", "45545845454", new Callback<Model>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Model> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i have created a post on retrofit 2.0..if anyone still facing this problem check it..[Retrofit 2.0 android](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/12/retrofit-20-android-example-web.html)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There is difference in Asynchronous in Retrofit 1.9 and 2.0

/* Synchronous in Retrofit 1.9 */

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("/list")
Repo loadRepo();

}
```

/* Asynchronous in Retrofit 1.9 */

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("/list")
void loadRepo(Callback<Repo> cb);

}
```

But on Retrofit 2.0, it is far more simple since you can declare with only just a single pattern

```
/* Retrofit 2.0 */

public interface APIService {

@POST("/list")
Call<Repo> loadRepo();

}
```

// Synchronous Call in Retrofit 2.0

```
Call<Repo> call = service.loadRepo();
Repo repo = call.execute();
```

// Asynchronous Call in Retrofit 2.0

```
Call<Repo> call = service.loadRepo();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Repo>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<Repo> response) {

   Log.d("CallBack", " response is " + response);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

  Log.d("CallBack", " Throwable is " +t);
}
});
```

Answer (score 25):

You can always do:

```
@POST("/endpoint")
Call<Void> postSomething();
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using RxJava, since 1.1.1 you can use [Completable](https://static.javadoc.io/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.1/rx/Completable.html) class.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/297

Please go through this link.

"*All interface declarations will be required to return an object through which all interaction will occur. The behavior of this object will be similar to a Future and will be generic typed (T) for the success response type.*"

```
@GET("/foo")
Call<Foo> getFoo();
```

Based on the new Retrofit 2.0.0 beta You cannot specify return type as void to make it asynchronous

as per the code inside retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/MethodHandler.java) it will show exception when you try the previous implementation with 2.0.0 beta

```
if (returnType == void.class) {
throw Utils.methodError(method, "Service methods cannot return void.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your classes, it looks like you are using Retrofit 2.0.0, which is currently in beta. I think using a void in your service method is no longer allowed. Instead, return [Call](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Call.html), which you can enqueue to perform the network call asynchronously.

Alternatively, drop your library down to Retrofit 1.9.0 and replace your Retrofit class with RestAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

just add suspend keyword to function in remote data source (api & service & end points interface)