# Retrofit 2 post error

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using `Retrofit2` and i wanna post our server to get some json data.So i have 2 classes. This is my response class:

```
public class RegisterToken {

private String accessToken;
private String tokenType;
private Integer expiresIn;
private String refreshToken;
private String asClientId;
private String Issued;
private String Expires;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();

public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

//and the other setter and getter,actually dont write cuz its too long

}
```

And then this is my API post interface :

```
public interface APIService {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("token")
public Callback<RegisterToken>  getRegisterToken(@Header("Accept")String accept,
    @Header("Content-Type")String contentType,@Header("register") String registerActive, 
    @Field("grant_type") String grantType,@Field("client_id") String clientId,
    @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,Callback<RegisterToken> callback);
}
```

In activity i am doing this  :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();

    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.base_api_url))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();


    APIService service = client.create(APIService.class);
    Callback<RegisterToken> registerToken=service.getRegisterToken("application/json", 
        "application/json", "active", grant_type, client_id, client_secret,
        new Callback<RegisterToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Response<RegisterToken> response) {
            Log.v("good","okkay");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.v("bad","shithapp");
        }
    });
```

And this is postman screenshot of what i want to do :
[image: Postman Screenshot]

So i am getting this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for
retrofit2.Callback<RegisterToken> for method APIService.getRegisterToken
```

What's wrong here i can't find ,i had tried and looked many Stackoverflow questions and cant find solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface `APIService`, change the return type of `getRegisterToken(...)` to `void`. You will be notified of the POST result via the last callback parameter.

So also remove `Callback<RegisterToken> registerToken =` before `service.getRegisterToken`.

Comment: First thank you for reply. I tried your things and get this error :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void.
 for method APIService.getRegisterToken

Comment: Oh you are using Retrofit 2, sorry, didn't notice. See this SO answer about how your structure should look like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32614103/1395437

Comment: i tried marked anser on your link but same error again
you can see my code is here : https://codeshare.io/CXpwR

Comment: Can you copy the full stack trace to your post?

Comment: this is my error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Call<com.yasinkacmaz.model.RegisterToken> for method APIService.getRegisterToken

Comment: i gave you full trace. but i didnt find solution i looked maybe 30 website and stackoverflow page but nothing :(

Comment: Sorry, but I'm also clueless

Comment: At least u tried to help.maybe i just dont use retrofit.can u suggest me another library ?

Comment: Retrofit is OK, but I woul suggest version 1.9.x. There are a lot of tutorials for that version.

Comment: How can i convert my code to 1.x version please help me ^^

Comment: I see you were successful.