# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm writing in Kotlin and trying to incorporate Retrofit2 into my code, using this call: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=Hello

This is my interface:

```
interface MyApiService {
    companion object {
        val myApiService by lazy {
            RealiApiService.create()
        }

        private fun create(): MyApiService {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/")
                    .build()

            return retrofit.create(RealiApiService::class.java)
        }
    }

    fun executeCall(call: Call<Any>) {
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Any> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Any>, response: Response<Any>) {
                Log.d("response is ${response.body()}")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Throwable is $t")
            }
        })
    }

    @GET("api.php")
    fun searchArtist(@Query("action") action: String,
                     @Query("format") format: String,
                     @Query("list") list: String,
                     @Query("srsearch") srsearch: String):
            Call<Any>
}
```

And this is my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        beginSearch("Hello")
    }

    private fun beginSearch(srsearch: String) {
        val call = realiApiService.searchArtist("query", "json", "search", srsearch)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Any> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Any>, response: Response<Any>) {
                Log.d("response is ${response.body()}")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Throwable is $t")
            }
        })

        //myApiService.executeCall(call)
    }
}
```

The code above works perfectly.
Do note, however, I have the exact same code in beginSearch and in MyApiService's executeCall(). If I comment out the line and use it instead of what I have now, I'll get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void.", and I'm not sure why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`executeCall` shouldn't be a method of `MyAPIService`. Retrofit tries to handle it along with other methods and can't, because as the error message says ["Service methods cannot return void"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311531/service-methods-cannot-return-void-retrofit). So it can't create the service and throws the exception. Without that line, `myApiService` is never created.

The interface passed to Retrofit should be just an interface (without implementations) and only contain request methods annotated with `@GET`/`@POST`/etc.

Just put it basically anywhere else.