# Recyclerview displays sometimes "null", sometimes my data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my `Recyclerview` and I can not find a solution to resolve it. Indeed, my `Recyclerview` is supposed to display data received from an external database. But sometimes, it displays the data, sometimes not.

This is the **screenshots** of my app :

[When data are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dECNd.png)

[When data are not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAQq0.png)

And this is my **Adapter's code** :

```
public class UpcomingLessonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UpcomingLessonAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Lesson> lessons;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public UpcomingLessonAdapter(List<Lesson> lessons, Context context) {
    this.lessons = lessons;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upcoming_lesson_list_view, parent, false);
    itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    return new UpcomingLessonAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Lesson lesson = lessons.get(position);

    String lessonTopic = "<font color='#E166E1'>" + lesson.getTopicTitle() + "</font>";
    String userName = "<font color='#E166E1'>" + lesson.getUserName() + "</font>";

    holder.lessonTopic.setText(Html.fromHtml(lesson.getTime(lesson.getTimeStart()) + " " + lessonTopic));
    holder.lessonTeacher.setText(Html.fromHtml("avec " + userName));
    holder.lessonDuration.setText(lesson.getDuration());
    holder.lessonDay.setText(lesson.getDay(lesson.getTimeStart()));
    holder.lessonMonth.setText(lesson.getMonth(lesson.getTimeStart()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lessons.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView lessonTopic, lessonTeacher, lessonDuration, lessonDay, lessonMonth;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        lessonTopic = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_topic_text_view);
        lessonTeacher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_teacher_text_view);
        lessonDuration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_duration_text_view);
        lessonDay = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lessson_day_text_view);
        lessonMonth = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_month_text_view);
    }
}
```

}

And this the method in my fragment when I create the recyclerview :

```
public void displayUpcomingLessonListView() {
    upcomingLessonRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.upcoming_lesson);
    upcomingLessonAdapter = new UpcomingLessonAdapter(upcomingLessons, getContext());
    upcomingLessonLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    upcomingLessonRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(upcomingLessonLayoutManager);
    upcomingLessonRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    upcomingLessonRecyclerView.setAdapter(upcomingLessonAdapter);
}
```

Is there anyone who can give me some advice ? Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

**EDIT**

This the method by which I fetch my data :

```
public void getLessonInfos(final int lessonId, final int index, final List<Lesson> lessons) {
    Call<JsonResponse> call = service.getLessonInfos(lessonId, user.getEmail(), user.getToken());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response<JsonResponse> response) {
            lessons.get(index).setUserName(response.body().getUserName());
            lessons.get(index).setTopicTitle(response.body().getTopicTitle());
            lessons.get(index).setTopicGroupTitle(response.body().getTopicGroupTitle());
            lessons.get(index).setLevel(response.body().getLevelTitle());
            lessons.get(index).setDuration(response.body().getDuration().getHours(), response.body().getDuration().getMinutes());
            lessons.get(index).setStatus(response.body().getLessonStatus());


            if (upcomingLessons.size() > 0) {
                if (lessonId == upcomingLessons.get(upcomingLessons.size() - 1).getLessonId()) {
                    displayUpcomingLessonListView();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try to initialize the String like (String a="";) in your getter and setter class or POGO class

Comment: I think it won't change anything. Normally my recyclerview is supposed to display data but instead it displays "null" or nothing if I initialize my strings

Comment: Try to use [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) instead of `Html.fromHtml`.

Comment: And post your `Lesson` class code please.

Comment: Are you able to get the data in LOG.d("",""+LessonTopic)?

Comment: ' But sometimes, it displays the data, sometimes not.' are you sure that data has been received correctly?

Comment: @Wivi0 How are you fetching the data? is it from an API? Can you post the code on how u r fetching data from the API?

Comment: Indeed, sometimes, I get all my data, sometimes only a part of them. I use Retrofit to get data from my database.

Comment: well that makes sense,the data source is asynchronous in nature.

Comment: try using execute which makes it synchronous.

Comment: @Wivi0 Then you are fetching the data is async way. You need a callback function to set the data to the adapter.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/17034466/2393309

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
         ResponseBody response = call.execute().body();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Alright when you invoke methods asynchronously , the network makes a request then , waits for a response. The latency or rather rather time will vary based on your connection speed(bytes per second) or rather your data-set(lots of data ,take time to process). Therefore the reason why your code sometime works is because some time the request and response time is fast enough to update your data in time.The snippet above remove the aforementioned method ,thus divorcing the concept of waiting for response. It makes a request synchronously and gets a response immediately. There is no wait time, the only time waited is the time to get the data from what ever source it is stored, process such data, transform it and send it off.

Comment: enqueue makes your request asynchronous, but execute makes it synchronous. just manipulate response object now,make sense?

Comment: Yes :-) Thank you !

Comment: no problem, however just make sure that your data set is small. Ill provide a more in dept explanation for this hack. Both the bad and good.

Comment: @CaspainCaldion Hi, please provide some context for the code, maybe edit your comments and use them in your answer? 
Useful resource for answering - stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator like

`holder.lessonDuration.setText(lesson.getDuration()!=null?lesson.getDuration():"");`